# How to change the column values of df1 with respect to single value in selected row of df2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df1` as shown below, rows in `df1` are selected using start and end date of `df2`. As you can see `CaseName` in `df2` have ID-numbers associated.

Problem:
I want to update/change/replace the `CaseName` in `df1` (selected by masked datetime stamp w.r.t. `df2`) with `CaseName` in `df2`.

Original shape of `df` is (80000,15) Rest columns are property values.
After Selection using Start and End date

```
df1.shape = (29467,15)
Index CaseName TStamp
0     CASE_A   2016-05-19 00:00
1     CASE_A   2016-05-19 01:00
2     CASE_A   2016-05-19 02:00
3     CASE_A   2016-05-19 03:00
4     CASE_A   2016-05-19 04:00
5     CASE_B   2016-07-30 00:00
6     CASE_B   2016-07-30 02:00
7     CASE_B   2016-07-30 03:00
8     CASE_B   2016-07-30 04:00
9     CASE_B   2016-07-30 05:00
10    CASE_B   2016-07-30 06:00
```

```
df2.shape = (23,3)
Index CaseName    Start      End
0     CASE_A1     2016-05-19 2016-08-30
1     CASE_A2     2016-08-30 2017-01-06
2     CASE_A3     2017-01-06 2017-05-08
3     CASE_A4     2017-05-08 2017-08-01
4     CASE_A5     2017-08-01 2018-06-24
5     CASE_B1     2016-05-20 2016-07-30
6     CASE_B2     2016-07-30 2016-10-16
7     CASE_B3     2016-10-16 2017-01-14
8     CASE_B4     2017-01-14 2017-05-08
9     CASE_B5     2017-05-08 2017-08-03
10    CASE_B6     2017-08-03 2018-06-25
```

I tried,

- iter row-by-row in `df2`.
- Create mask using `df2.Start` and `df2.End`.
- Applied condition to assign values.
- Actually there are multiple cases CASE_A,B,C,D in `df1`.

```py
#For single condition CASE_A
for index,row in df2.iterrows():
    mask = (df1['TStamp'] > row['Start']) & (df1['TStamp'] <= row['End'])
    temp_df = df1.loc[mask]
    temp_df.loc[temp_df['CaseName'] == 'CASE_A','CaseName'] = row['CaseName ']
```

Expected output is something like,

```
result_df1.shape = (29467,15)
Index CaseName TStamp
0     CASE_A1   2016-05-19 00:00
1     CASE_A1   2016-05-19 01:00
2     CASE_A1   2016-05-19 02:00
3     CASE_A1   2016-05-19 03:00
4     CASE_A1   2016-05-19 04:00
5     CASE_B2   2016-07-30 00:00
6     CASE_B2   2016-07-30 02:00
7     CASE_B2   2016-07-30 03:00
8     CASE_B2   2016-07-30 04:00
9     CASE_B2   2016-07-30 05:00
10    CASE_B2   2016-07-30 06:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert columns to datetimes
df1['TStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['TStamp'])
df2['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Start'])
df2['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['End'])

#remove last value in strings
df2['CaseName'] = df2['CaseName'].str[:-1]

#merge together
df = df1.merge(df2, on='CaseName')
#filter by condition and by columns names
mask = (df['TStamp'] > df['Start']) & (df['TStamp'] <= df['End'])
df = df.loc[mask, df1.columns]
print (df)
   CaseName              TStamp
5    CASE_A 2016-05-19 01:00:00
10   CASE_A 2016-05-19 02:00:00
15   CASE_A 2016-05-19 03:00:00
20   CASE_A 2016-05-19 04:00:00
25   CASE_B 2016-07-30 00:00:00
32   CASE_B 2016-07-30 02:00:00
38   CASE_B 2016-07-30 03:00:00
44   CASE_B 2016-07-30 04:00:00
50   CASE_B 2016-07-30 05:00:00
56   CASE_B 2016-07-30 06:00:00
```

Comment: Hey thanks for such a prompt reply. I think this solution is close. I tried it. but as mentioned above I want to convert `CASE_A` of `df1` into `CASE_A1/2/3/4` with reference to `df2`. See,  `df2` has 3 columns `CaseName,Start,End`.  There are 22 obervations. I selected rows in `df1` using start-end of `df2`. Next `CaseName` for that interval in `df2` is `CASE_A11`, and that needs to be replaces into `df1`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all date columns have been converted to datetime. This following approach uses [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) which checks whether a value belongs to a range

```
(df2.assign(CaseName1=df2.CaseName.str[:-1])
    .join(df1.set_index('CaseName'), on='CaseName1')
    .loc[lambda x:x.TStamp.between(x.Start,x.End),['CaseName','TStamp']])
```